# Bash copy all directory with content that matches a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, sh

Is there some way to copy the directories including the contents using bash script. For example

```
// Suppose there are many directory inside Test in c as,
   /media/test/
        -- en_US
                -- file1
                -- file 2 
        -- de_DE 
               -- file 1
               -- SUB-dir1
                  -- sub file 1
               -- file 2
               .....
               .....
        -- Test 1
              --  testfile1
              -- folder
                   --- more 1  
         ............

NoW i want to copy all the directories (including sub-directory and files)
to another location which matches the pattern.
--> for example , in above case I want the directories en_US and de_DE to be copied in another
location including sub-directories and files.
```

So Far I have done/ find out :

1) Needed Pattern as , `/b/w{2}_/w{2}/b`

2) I can list all the directories as ,

```
$MYDIR="/media/test/"
DIRS=`ls -l $MYDIR | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $10}'`
for DIR in $DIRS
do
echo  ${DIR}
done
```

Now I need help in combining these together so that the script can copy all the directory(including sub contents) that matches the pattern to another location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just don't see how you intend to put those 2 things together to give a sensible result. However, from my rather limited interpretation of what it is that you are trying to achieve, have a look at the command `ls -aR1 ./directory_name` which will provide you with a comprehensive list of what is within a directory

Comment: bash is a UNIX shell. UNIX has no `folders`, it has `directories`, and UNIX paths are not separated by backslashes `\ `, they are separated by forward slashes `/`. It sounds like the UNIX command you want is just `cp -r olddir newdir`.

Comment: @EdMorton: I did change the structure. well if the directory were known then it could be easier just to copy all the required directories to a new location . But the situation is, There could be 1000s of folders with structure for ex. `aa_bb` i.e. 2 characters then underscore then again two characters. I need to find and copy all those directories with this format to a new location.

Comment: It's funny that you changed folder to directory in your question and then went on to describe the 1000s of **folders** .... :-). Please edit your question to show some a more concrete example of input AND output if the simple `cp -r` command isn't what you need. Given no-one is suggesting anything else, clearly that's all we think you need given what you've told us so far so if it's not what you need you need to edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To selectively copy an entire directory structure to a similar directory structure, while filtering the contents, in a general way your best bet is to archive the original directory and unarchive. For instance, using GNU Tar:

```
$ mkdir destdir
$ tar -c /media/test/{en_US,de_DE} | tar -C destdir -x --strip-components=1
```

In this example, the `/media/test` directory structure is partially recreated under `destdir`, excluding the `/media` prefix (thanks to `--strip-components=1`).

The left side `tar` archives just the directories/paths which match the pattern that we specified. The archive is produced on that command's standard output, which is piped to the decoding `tar` on the right hand side. The `-C` tells it to change to the destination directory. It extracts the files there, removing a leading path component.

```
$ ls destdir
test
$ ls destdir/test
en_US de_DE
```

Of course, your specific example test case is quite easily handled with `cp -a`:

```
$ mkdir destdir
$ cp -a /media/test/{en_US,de_DE} destdir
```

If the pattern is complicated, involving multiple selections of subtree material at deeper and/or different levels of the source directory hierarchy, then you need the more general approach, if you wish to do the copy in a single batch command which just specifies source patterns.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your environment, but I guess you try to do this:

```
cp -r src_dir/??_?? dest_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your starter for 10:
You will have to add the extra checks and balances that you require but it should give you a flying start.

```
#!/bin/bash
# assumes $1 is source to search and $2 to destination to copy to
subdirs=`find $1 -name ??_?? -print`
echo $subdirs
for x in $subdirs
do
        echo $x
        cp -a $x $2
done
```

Comment: Note that I have removed the : (colon) that was at the end of the `for x in $subdirs`, as this caused an error on the last line of any list produced by adding on the colon to the end of the file name

Answer (score -1):

Please check if this is what you wanted. It searches for directories with format xx_yy/ab_cd/&&_$$ (2char_2char) and copies the content to a new directory .

```
usage : ./script.sh

cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash

MYDIR="/media/test/"
NEWDIRPATH="/media/test_new"
DIRS=`ls -l $MYDIR | grep "^d" | awk '{print $9}'`
for DIR in $DIRS
do
        total_characters=`echo $DIR | wc -m`
        if [ $total_characters -eq 6 ]; then
                has_underscore=`echo "$DIR" | grep "_"`
                if [ "$has_underscore" != "" ]; then
                        echo "${DIR}"
                        start_string_count=`echo $DIR | awk -F '_' '{print $1}' | wc -m`
                        end_string_count=`echo $DIR | awk -F '_' '{print $2}' | wc -m`
                        echo "start_string_count => $start_string_count ; end_string_count => $end_string_count"
                        if [ $start_string_count -eq 3 ] && [ $end_string_count -eq 3 ]; then
                                mkdir -p $NEWDIRPATH/"$DIR"_new
                                cp -r $DIR $NEWDIRPATH/"$DIR"_new
                        fi
                fi
        fi
done
```